# Azure App service restrictions not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have the following setup on azure:

- 1 app service for .NET backend
- 1 app service for angular frontend with a custom domain
- 1 SQL server

I created a virtual network, I added 2 subnets for frontend and backend.I assigned these subnets to application services.

I would like to allow only the frontend to access my backend but my frontend receives 403 from my backend.

I created Access Restrictions that allow only inbound connection from the subnet, or IP but my frontend receives 403 when is trying to access it. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: IP address based restrictions are not going to work for you as you are not in `App Service Environment`. For subnet based restriction, in process of enabling it, did you also enable service endpoints in the subnet?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes I enabled service endpoints and I also tried with security groups but I cannot achieve what I want. Do you know any other approach outside App Service Environment?

Comment: Alternate approach is to use `Private Endpoints`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting `403` which implies forbidden, so looked like an access issue here.

As per the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions?tabs=azurecli#permissions), you may need to provide permissions as well to the subnet or at a higher level.

[image]

Comment: I created a Private Endpoint and attached to subnet for API. I disabled public access from API that allows only Private Endpoints connections. I created a Network Security Group that allows Virtual Network and App Service Connection. Frontend and Backend are both in same virtual network, different subnets. I still have the same issue. I think I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Late Update:

I managed to solve this by adding a NGINX server in front of the Azure App service.